# notepad ++ formatting data into actual table/columns

Tags: notepad++

I have this table which is basically a line of explanation headers and then separate lines with a bunch of numbers and such corresponding to those headers, each separated by a single tab on their line. This causes the whole thing to look like one big jumbled mess, and none of the numbers line up with the headers at the top. I am trying to find some way to get it to all line up so that it's readable like a normal table. Hope this is an actually fixable problem.

Comment: Maybe you can try put semicolon instead tab?

Answer (score 12):

I come across this alot myself when I want to have a Table made into a Text which is readable.  I did find a website that worked pretty well (https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables); inspite of the fact that I reallly want to do this easily in Notepad++.  I tried the **Notepad++ TextFX plugin** from answer by Terel `TextFX` --> `TextFX Edit` --> `Line up multiple lines by (Clipboard Character)`, but that did not work like I was expecting.

### ORIGINAL (input)

I have a table like this in Excel...

[image]

... and I copy it to Notepad it looks like this...

```
Sheet   Range   Old Value   New Value   Description
z_PublicConstants               Module Procedure: btnSubmit_ModelParamDate Deleted.
z_PublicConstants               Module Procedure: ResultSet_ModelParamDate Deleted.
ThisWorkbook                Module Procedure: Workbook_Open Changed.
z_PublicConstants               Module Procedure: OpenConnection_ProductionPlanning Changed.
z_PublicConstants               Module Procedure: btnResultSet_SynchronizeAll Changed.
```

### FORMATTED (output)

What I think you want it for it be a textual format that is readable in table format. This was created with **Tables Generator website** link I provided.

```
+-------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Sheet             | Range | Old Value | New Value | Description                                                  |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| z_PublicConstants |       |           |           | Module Procedure: btnSubmit_ModelParamDate Deleted.          |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| z_PublicConstants |       |           |           | Module Procedure: ResultSet_ModelParamDate Deleted.          |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| ThisWorkbook      |       |           |           | Module Procedure: Workbook_Open Changed.                     |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| z_PublicConstants |       |           |           | Module Procedure: OpenConnection_ProductionPlanning Changed. |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| z_PublicConstants |       |           |           | Module Procedure: btnResultSet_SynchronizeAll Changed.       |
+-------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Notepad++ TextFX plugin** from answer by Terel `TextFX` --> `TextFX Edit` --> `Line up multiple lines by (Clipboard Character)` did not work, it just removed the TAB characters, like this...

```
Sheet Range Old Value New Value Description
z_PublicConstants    Module Procedure: btnSubmit_ModelParamDate Deleted.
z_PublicConstants    Module Procedure: ResultSet_ModelParamDate Deleted.
ThisWorkbook    Module Procedure: Workbook_Open Changed.
z_PublicConstants    Module Procedure: OpenConnection_ProductionPlanning Changed.
z_PublicConstants    Module Procedure: btnResultSet_SynchronizeAll Changed.
```

Comment: As pointed out in my answer I also hat problems with the TAB delimiter and suggested a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

Purely within Notepad++, you could go to Menu -> **Settings** -> **Preferences** -> **Tab settings**, then select the extension for your file and set a large enough tab size. You might also want to set it to replace tabs with spaces.

As you enter text into the file, type TAB between fields and the correct number of spaces should be added to make the fields line up.

If you need to do this often then it may be best to create a new file type so Notepad++ remembers the tab settings for this one file type and it does not affect other file types. Otherwise, you may need to change the tabs settings for the selected file back to its original values to avoid unwanted tabbing in a future edit.

Comment: What do I do if my bits of data vary in length? changing the tab size enough to make everything fit would be way too much space for most of the columns.

Comment: @Rothgar - You are asking for something that Notepad++ does not provide. You could ask the Notepad++ developers to add it, or as it is open source (I think it is), you could add the feature yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the plugin **TextFX**. Once installed via **Plugins** --> **Plugin Manager** you can copy the delimiter and select **TextFX** --> **TextFX Edit** --> **Line up multiple lines by (Clipboard Character)**

Note that I had problems using the tab character as a delimiter. As a workaround I replaced all tabs with another character which was not used in my file (like #) and used this one as a delimiter. Once my lines where lined up correctly I replaced the character with the tab character again.

Answer (score 4):

This site helped me:
https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

1. Go to File - New Table.
2. Define your number rows and columns (you can easily delete what's too much)
3. Paste your table
4. Copy with button ("copy") and paste into your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 simple solutions using MS Excel
(I know, not notepad++ but maybe it still is okay for you):
- first is that you replace the TAB with semicolon, save it as .csv and open it with Excel.
- second you open Excel -> Data -> From Text ... within the Assistant on step 2 you have to choose TAB

Answer (score 0):

Purely within Notepad++, you could go to Menu -> Settings -> Preferences -> Tab settings, then select the extension for your file and set a large enough tab size. You might also want to set it to replace tabs with spaces.

As you enter text into the file, type TAB between fields and the correct number of spaces should be added to make the fields line up.

If you need to do this often then it may be best to create a new file type so Notepad++ remembers the tab settings for this one file type and it does not affect other file types. Otherwise, you may need to change the tabs settings for the selected file back to its original values to avoid unwanted tabbing in a future edit.

Answer (score 0):

Real text tables are available in Emacs: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode  with a table mode. Their behavior is similar to Excel in many cases.

Comment: Question is about Notepad++